# Loop through array and pass array data to properties in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, highcharts

So I have this problem. I'm working with highchairs and I'm trying to make some dynamic charts.

But I'm having some problem with passing array data to a property javascript object. Let me explain better by adding some code :

So this is the JSON

```
{
  "businessId": 1,
  "surveyName": "test",
  "year": "2019",
  "period": "november",
  "kp": [{
    "id": 7,
    "title": "Standard Test",
    "widgetType": "Bar",
    "goal": null,
    "trend": null,
    "data": {
      "questions": ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"],
      "seriesValue": [{
        "test values"
      }]
    }
  }, {
    "id": 8,
    "title": "% of usual sample",
    "widgetType": "Pie",
    "goal": null,
    "trend": null,
    "data": {
      "slice": [20, 30, 50],
      "discardReasons": ["Reason1", "Reason2", "Reason3"]
    }
  }]
}
```

And this is the code to create the piechart:

```
var piechart = Highcharts.chart('container-pie-1', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Septembre, 2019'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: true
  },
  navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Discrad Reasons',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: dynamic names,
      y: dynamic data
    }]
  }]
});
```

inside the **series** property there are supposed to be multiple names and multiple ~***y***~ data. I would like to fill it looping through the JSON array.

```
For example : 

//now it's like this
series: [{
  name: 'Discrad Reasons',
  colorByPoint: true,
  data: [{
    name: 'Wrong Email',
    y: 61.41,
    sliced: true,
    selected: true
  }, {
    name: 'Business not found',
    y: 11.84
  }, {
    name: 'Etc',
    y: 10.85
  }, {
    name: 'Etc',
    y: 4.67
  }, {
    name: 'Etc',
    y: 4.18
  }, {
    name: 'Other',
    y: 7.05
  }]
}]

//and I want something dynamic like this

series: [{
    name: 'Discrad Reasons',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: loop through json array,
        y: loop through json array
    }]
}]
```

Can anyone give any idea?

Comment: Hi @Pavel, Could you describe which values from JSON you want to show on a chart?

Comment: Hello @ppotaczek . You can see the json I have at the beginnig of the code. Also you can see at the last part of the code, how the data is right now and how I would like it to be

Comment: Yes, I now, but I still do not understand which values should be map to `y` or `name`.